# Background-image is not showing up

Tags: html, css

Yesterday I was making an HTML element and this problem hit me up.
The Background-image of the DIV is not showing, and I was curious, the link worked fine.

Here is my code

```html
<div id="floating-image-<?php echo $id; ?>" class="fl-<?php echo $id; ?>" style="
    background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/290470/pexels-photo-290470.jpeg?h=350&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb);
    margin-top: 20px;
   height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-position: center center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   transform: translateY(0px);
    background-size: contain;
   position: relative;
    margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 80%;
    display:block;
    "></div>
```

**EDIT**
ok, I edited the dynamic codes and replaced them with some static output.
Sorry for misleading
**Another EDIT**
I changed the image and now I am using a smaller image, but still it doesn't show up

Comment: What is `$image` and what does your file structure look like? Check your console to see if you're getting errors. There isn't much else we can do here.

Comment: Does you width and height have `px` on it? If not then you're creating a div with either no width, no height, or both, and therefore your background image is showing up, just on a div that isn't visible (because it's width/height is 0)

Comment: @Santi I checked my console but nothing was there about the picture

Comment: @Adam Yes, I have the width and the height stated in PX

Comment: Give your element a background colour (or border)  so you can see where it it is on the screen, do you see the element?

Comment: I think it should be `background-image: url('http://url-here');`
Notice the `' '`

Comment: @P_95 - quotes don't matter

Comment: What I figured out till now is that this element works on Codepen but not in my project, which made it weird. I checked inspect element for any old rule or class that made this element not showing, but nothing was there. Although, I did conclude something, and it is that the picture is not showing, only the image

Comment: @AlyHassan - your code works fine standalone, so there's something else on your page (or maybe in your environment) that we don't know about that's causing it not to work. See this: https://jsfiddle.net/tfw457oq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is going to be solved only by me since it is included in a project.

Thanks for your help, and if I found the real solution, I will post it here.

**EDIT**

Well, I feel bad now, about the wasted hour in my life.

Anyway, I found the solution and it was about the animations.
I made this feature in my theme, so the user could create animations easily.

The whole story summerizes in few words, " Didn't enable animations in the parent Section, So the normal css code goes as .class{**OPACITY:0;**} ".

Sorry! and Thanks for your deep concern in such a problem

Comment: In the future, learning how to inspect your element with dev tools would've saved you an hour.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked, background image is properly working. Your image size is very big, approx 7 MB. Reduce it upto 300KB, too big to show.

Comment: I changed the image with a smaller one, but it didn't show up

Comment: While it's certainly good advice to not use a 7MB image as a backgrond-image of a 200px square div, this fact alone will not prevent it from loading.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in the image,
You have used very high quality image.
if you use a low quality image than you have currently used,
it will work fine.